# Criptografando script de funções e Procedures no MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Uma duvida, tenho algumas functions e procedures customizadas e não quero que o meu cliente (que tem acesso ao banco) fique mexendo no script delas. Alguém conhece alguma forma nativa do MSSQL de criptografar esses códigos ?

Comment: veja se ajudar , https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2964/encrypting-and-decrypting-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-and-userdefined-functions/

Comment: Obrigado @MarconcilioSouza, ajudou, por que utilizando o `WITH ENCRYPTION` já me auxilia no que eu preciso e inibe qualquer cliente curioso de alterar o script.

Comment: Sua pergunta é bastante redundante se o seu cliente tem acesso ao banco de dados.

Comment: Olá @Lacobus, não é redundante não, e o link enviado pelo MarconcilioSouza já me auxiliou no meu questionamento.

Answer (score 2):

Se você precisa que algo que você entregou ao cliente seja secreto, você já perdeu esse jogo de gato e rato. Na verdade você já estava derrotado antes mesmo do jogo começar.

[O próprio artigo mencionado nos comentários](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2964/encrypting-and-decrypting-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-and-userdefined-functions/) mostra como é trivial decriptar as funções e os procedimentos encriptados com `WITH_ENCRYPTION`. E com acesso de escrita no banco, o seu cliente poderá editar a lógica a vontade. Se ele não estiver preocupado em manter a sua lógica, ele nem precisa decriptar a sua, basta sobrescrever com uma lógica nova sem nem ler a antiga.

Alguém poderia sugerir que se você quer manter sua lógica de banco intacta, você pode manter as queries na aplicação. Além de isso ser menos performático do que ter funções e procedimentos no banco, **não existe código fonte que não possa ser descompilado**, então acabamos por voltar à estaca zero.

Se você não quer que sua lógica seja lida ou alterada, a única forma é vender serviço ao invés de código. Mantenha a aplicação e o banco em um servidor ao qual somente você tem acesso. Qualquer outra solução que te ofereçam é óleo de cobra.